# Standard practice for user-requested server intermediate files

Tags: sql, database, file

Let's say a user makes a request to load some data from a database on a server and an intermediate file of the requested data to be loaded into the browser is generated. What is the standard practice for what to do with this file? Let it be overwritten? Delete it after a certain amount of time?

More details: the intermediate file is a CSV file needed to display javascript graphs. It consists of date/time and float pairs, and should be no more than 1 MB. It should be running linux, SQLite database. The user should be able to select some data to display over time. The file is generated server side with an asynchronous request (ajax). I am not sure I need an intermediate file, but it seems difficult to otherwise get data out of a sql database (working with sql only in javascript has a speed issue). The server side (PHP) is currently just PHP executing a command having SQLite run some SQL. I suppose running SQLite through PHP would remove the need for the file, but my question about if a file were generated still stands.

Comment: Why do you generate that intermediate file? What kind of data, what size? What database and operating system are you using? What application? What protocols? Please **edit your question** to improve it (give more details and motivation)

Comment: Is the intermediate file on server side, or on browser side? What kind of request (HTTP?) is making it? Are you sure you *need* an intermediate file?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It is generated server side with an asynchronous request (ajax). I am not sure I need an intermediate file, but it seems difficult to otherwise get data out of a sql database (working with sql only in javascript has a speed issue).

Comment: Please *edit your question*, don't comment it to give significant details

Comment: How is the server side programmed (PHP?)? What make you believe you need an intermediate *file*? It could be removed on the server just after replying to the HTTP request... Especially for a small content of a megabyte, keeping it only in memory could make sense...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Alright, I managed to get sqlite3 running with PHP and avoid temporary files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you generate some file *server-side* to respond to some given HTTP request, you can remove that file after sending the HTTP response.

You may do some memoization, if you believe that the *same* request will give the *same* temporary file later (but that may be very unlikely).

If for whatever reason you cannot remove the file quickly, you might have some cleanup procedure, e.g. some [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job running every hour and removing files older than two hours. You'll better have a dedicated subdirectory for these temporary files.

BTW, in your particular case, you probably should *avoid* creating temporary files, and generate that content in memory only.